# Is using "now" redundant?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, synonyms, redundancy

Which is correct?

It pervades our lives now as it did yesterday.

It pervades our lives as it did yesterday.

I think the word "pervades" suggests that it is happening now. Adding "now" would be redundant. Am I wrong?

Comment: The meaning is clearer with *now* included. *Today* would be even better since it contrasts directly with *yesterday*.

Comment: I agree with Mick; having the explicit comparison is much clearer.

Comment: Redundancies are not always the foul things some imagine. You'd get some strange looks if you said something had gone to _rack_.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Quite. What does *going to rack and pinion* actually **mean**? ;-)

Comment: @Mick - It means you're having barbecue ribs seasoned with pine nuts.

Comment: @HotLicks I had forgotten about that one. I must have been drunk at the time.

Answer (score 0):

Well, no.  *Pervades* is more of a long term thing.  Here's an example of a sentence that would work:

> Hunger pervaded our lives that whole long post-war year.

It sounds strange for pervading to happen on a short time scale such as one day.